# DB2, getting averages using a case statement within

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2, I'm trying to get distinct fields in a GROUP BY while also getting avgs of certain values in each row.

The problem, I think, is that I'm trying to use CASE within an AVG clause

```
 SELECT
    number,
    customer,
    group,
    groupDetail,
    category,
    detail,
    detailName,
    avg(countOfSales),
    avg(annuals),
    avg(case when trajectory is null then 0 else trajectory end as trajectory),
    avg(annualsLocation),
    avg(case when trajLocation is null then 0 else trajLocation end as trajLocation),
    avg(annualsWhole),
    avg(case when trajWhole is null then 0 else trajWhole end as trajWhole)
FROM salesReporting
WHERE customer = 123
group by number,customer,group,groupDetail,category,detail,detailName
ORDER BY customer,groupDetail,category,detail ASC
```

So it says that 'AS' not expected as a token and I think it's within my first CASE within an AVG.

So with:

```
customer | group | groupDetail | category | detail | detailName | countOfSales | annuals | trajectory | annualsLocation | trajLocation | annualsWhole | trajWhole
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      12345           2948     124.84       8372                246.08        8372         28.84
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      12345           2345     164.84       4839                234.08        4839         26.63
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      12345           6523     224.84       2345                654.08        2345         29.85
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      12345           3456     134.84       5434                152.08        5434         25.34
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      12345           3426     124.84       6234                245.08        6234         28.84
```

I would want

```
customer | group | groupDetail | category | detail | detailName | countOfSales | annuals | trajectory | annualsLocation | trajLocation | annualsWhole | trajWhole
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123         1         Atl.          Sls       New       NewLoc      /*and all of these columns to be the respective averages of the matching columns above*/
```

How can I properly achieve that in DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a syntax issue, the alias "trajectory should be outside the avg bracket

Eg:

```
avg(case when trajectory is null then 0 else trajectory end) as trajectory
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! Can't believe I missed that, thank you... Do you also happen to know why, when using round(,2) it rounds the actual number to 2 digits after the decimal but still has a trail of zeroes behind?

Comment: I guess its to do with the client program/application which is displaying the output of the select query. I would try casting the output explicitly Eg: say as decimal follows to see if it helps ===>cast(round(<col>,2) as decimal)

Comment: The result type depends on the input type. Check out the manual page  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000845.html  "The data type and length attribute of the result are the same as the data type and length attribute of the first argument, except that the precision is increased by one if the numeric-expression1 is DECIMAL and the precision is less than 31"

Answer (score 0):

This logic is much more simply written using `coalesce()`:

```
avg(coalesce(trajectory, 0)) as trajectory,
. . .
```